# Python Pandas same value col A having col B value different

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

A **Pandas solution** to get result Dataframe when **values B are not same** for **same A value**

IN:

```
colA  colB
a     1 <--
b     2
a     1 <--
a     0 <-- different
```

OUT:

```
colA  colB
a     1 <--
a     1 <--
a     0 <-- different
```

SOLUTION:

[Pandas Groupby Select Groups that Have More Than One Unique Values in a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70236139/pandas-groupby-select-groups-that-have-more-than-one-unique-values-in-a-column)

```
out = df.groupby(['a']).filter(lambda x: x['b'].nunique() > 1)
```

@mozway comment works too

```
out = df[df.groupby('colA')['colB'].transform('nunique').gt(1)]
```

Comment: `out = df[df.groupby('colA')['colB'].transform('nunique').gt(1)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
result = df[df.duplicated(subset='colA', keep=False) | ~df.duplicated(subset='colA', keep=False)]
```

Then if you don't want duplicates:

```
result.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```